# Caret cross-validation following stepwise selection. Question on mechanism

Tags: r, logistic-regression, cross-validation, r-caret

Say that I have traindf with dimensions:

```
> dim(traindf)
[1] 5000   25
```

And I want to extract the a useful logistic regression model.
For it I have used caret code below using backward stepwise selection with 10-fold cross-validation.

```
trControl <- trainControl(method="cv", # K-folk Cross-validation
                          number = 10, # K = 10
                          savePredictions = T,
                          classProbs = T,
                          verboseIter = T,
                          summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

caret_model <- train(Class~.,
                     traindf,
                     method="glmStepAIC", # Step wise AIC
                     family="binomial", # Logistic regression is specified
                     direction="backward", # Backward selection
                     trace = F,
                     trControl=trControl)
```

The code works properly, it returns a model with 0.86 ROC.

My questions are on how the algorithm works.

1- I'm not sure whether stepwise selection selects, for each model with k-variables, the model with lowest deviance or AIC?

2- Does the algorithm cross-validate the best model from each k-variables and output the best from all of those or just cross-validate the best model based on AIC from step-wise selection?

Answer (score 1):

caret method `glmStepAIC` internally calls [`MASS::stepAIC`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MASS/versions/7.3-54/topics/stepAIC), therefore the answer to your first question is AIC is used for selection of variables.

To answer your second question. Caret partitions the data as you define in `trainControl`, which is in your case 10-fold CV. For each of the 10 training sets `glmStepAIC` is run, it selects the best model based on AIC and this model is used to predict on the respective CV test sets. The average performance of these predictions is reported under `caret_model$results`. After this a `glmStepAIC` is run on all of the supplied data and the optimal model based on AIC is selected, this model is stored in `caret_model$finalModel` and used to predict on new data.